# Zooming not working on SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am follwoing [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) to impliment zooing behavior on my svg drawing and the zoom behaviour is not working at all. There are no errors in the console. I wonder if this is because this is an svg drawing from inkscape.

**Fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/36/**

code

```
var changeArray = [-60,-40,-20,0,20,40,60];
var colorArray = ["#009870", "#36b18c", "#99cfb8", "#ffffbf", "#f39a93", "#e95058", "#e4003a"];

var colorDark2S = new Array();
var colorDark4S = new Array();
var invariant = 0;

var dataset;
    function checkIt(data){
     var data_clean = []; //prepared variable for clear data
    for (var i in data) {
      data_clean.push(data[i].Change_total);
      }

// tooltips
var w = 500,
    h = 500;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  //move initialisation here, to be sure dataset is there
  var main_svg =  d3.select("#level_0")
               .selectAll("path")
               .data(data_clean)
               .attr("stroke", "#888888")
               .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
               .attr("stroke-linejoin","round")
               .attr("stroke-linecap","round")
               .style("fill", function fill(data_clean){
                var color;
                if(data_clean < changeArray[0])
                             {color = colorArray[0]
                           colorDark4S[invariant] = true;}
                else {
                if(data_clean < changeArray[1])
                   {
                    color = colorArray[1]
                    colorDark4S[invariant] = true;
                     } else {
                    if(data_clean < changeArray[2])
                        {
                    color = colorArray[2]
                    colorDark4S[invariant] = true;
                     } else {
                      if(data_clean < changeArray[3])

                     {color = colorArray[3]
                       } else {
                      if(data_clean < changeArray[4])
                        {
                       color = colorArray[4]
                      } else {
                      if(data_clean < changeArray[5])
                       {
                         color = colorArray[5]
                       } else  {
                    color = colorArray[6]
                    colorDark4S[invariant] = true;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
                return color
               })
 .on("mouseout", function () {
    d3.select(this)
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("stroke", "#888888");
})
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
           d3.select(this)
          .style("stroke-width", "3px")
          .style("stroke", "#000")
          .attr("stroke-linejoin","round")
          .attr("stroke-linecap","round");

            })
  .call(zoom);

var container = main_svg.append("g");

function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

}

var svg_0 = d3.xml("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/301b01028c9976a3846a3a5b068ea5abe8de0d65/picture.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
    d3.select("#viz").node().appendChild(importedNode)
});

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/82cd19eff7db367193cf8ce00144a40ea8d140ac/data.json", checkIt);
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any mouse scroll event configured.. (for zooming)

Comment: How do I do that it is not clear from the example

Comment: Your zoom *is* working. The problem is, that you are not zooming anything. You are zooming on `container` which is an empty `g` appended to `main_svg`. You need to either move parts of your DOM inside the appended group or have `container` reference some other part of your DOM. This depends on what you are after. As a proof of concept you might just change the assignment to `var container = main_svg;` which will actually zoom the circle and its contents.

Comment: @altocumulus: Thank you so very much for your reply I cannot possibly express my gratitude in words. I have been toiling with this since morning

Comment: @altocumulus: Just another side question do in order to zoom in to the svg as a whole is that possible ?

Comment: @Imo As an aside, you should have a closer look at your asynchronous calls. Both, `d3.xml()` and `d3.json()` are async and will most likely execute in parallel causing some race condition. My first execution of your code failed for that reason. This could easily be solved by putting the call to `d3.json()` **inside** the callback provided to `d3.xml()`. This way function `checkIt()` will get called after the SVG `picture.svg` itself finished loading.

Comment: Do you really want to zoom in on the entire SVG? This will include buttons and labels as well. As you mentioned that the SVG itself will be an Inkscape graphic, it might be the best approach to put everything that is supposed to participate in zooming in one group while creating the image and register that group for the zoom behaviour.

Comment: okay I try that, Thankyou for your previous suggestion I wil change the code accordingly